# How to configure TFS2018 build vb.net with Nuget dependencies in Artifactory

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, artifactory

I am trying to configure a VB.Net project that has a reference to NuGet package that is stored in our Artifactory repository. I am trying to configure a build in TFS 2018 and I think that there maybe several ways to configure the build in TFS.

I used the .net desktop app template and then modified it. I have it configured as
Use NuGet 4.4.1
NuGet restore
Build Solution
Publish Symbols
Copy Files to ….
Publish Artifact: drop
 [image]

It’s failing at the NuGet restore:
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects
Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects%0D%0A Unable to find version '1.0.8' of package 'WPSArchiver-AnyCPU'.%0D%0A C:\Users\TFSBuild1_SVCACCT.nuget\packages: Package 'WPSArchiver-AnyCPU.1.0.8' is not found on source 'C:\Users\TFSBuild1_SVCACCT.nuget\packages\'.%0D%0A https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'WPSArchiver-AnyCPU.1.0.8' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.%0D%0A https://xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.com:8443/artifactory/api/nuget/wps-csat-nuget-local: The V2 feed at 'https:// xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.com:8443/artifactory/api/nuget/wps-csat-nuget-local/Packages(Id='WPSArchiver-AnyCPU',Version='1.0.8')' returned an unexpected status code '401 Unauthorized'.)
task result: Failed
Packages failed to restore

So it looks like it does try to access our local instance of Artifactory, but it is getting a '401 Unauthorized'
[image] 
As you can see in the image above I created a “Credentials for feeds…”  For this I created a Nuget authentication

Should I use different build steps?  How can I troubleshoot the authentication request. I know that the account that I am using is valid.

Comment: It looks like you got an answer to your question. In addition, I recommend you check out the Artifactory Nugey task, which makes the confirmation and usage easier. It is added by the Artifactory extension. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-TriggeringNugetBuilds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Feed URL in above service connection for local Artifactory server is not complete. The source URL pointing to Artifactory should be like this `http://severname:8081/artifactory/api/nuget/<repository key>`.

In your case you can try changing the Feed URL in above screen to `https://xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.com:8443/artifactory/api/nuget/wps-csat-nuget-local`

The Feed URL should be the same with the packageSources you defined in nuget.config file.

You can modify the setting for Credentials for feeds in the [Service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) section of in project settings.

**Project settings**--> **Service connections** under **Pipelines**-->Select your connection(CSAT Artifactory)--> Update the **Feed URL**.

If it is still not able to authenticate, you can try using the API Key for the **Password** field of the artifactory connection.

Hope above help!

Comment: Fixing the URL in the Credentials for Feeds fixed it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi@PatDelane I'm glad i could help. Could you accept it if you think it can serve as an answer. Thanks!